# Hidding file-browser when using download method

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to hide  the pop-up dialog box  when I invoke the download method and set the download destination path to be constant constant , in other words, I want to set the location where I wanna the file to be saved in advance .

Is this possible , any help in extremely appreciated. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to save files to arbitrary locations without using AIR.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im already using AIR, but everything I wanna do is hidding the pop-up dialog box which appears to locate where to save the file. is this possible ?